# Laravel project transfer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I worked as a prefect on the Laravel on my laptop. But when I wanted to transfer the project to another machine, an error appeared: "The MAC is invalid". What I can do with it?

Comment: What generates this error? The project? The computer? your question needs a bit more detail for this. If MAC is addressing the MAC address of the computer, then this has nothing to do with Laravel as Laravel does not bind itself to a single machine.

Comment: @killstreet The project generate this error when i try to run it in browser

Comment: This seems to be caused by column length limitations, read this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/daeling-with-decryptexceptioninvalid-data

Comment: @killstreet it didn't help me

Comment: Can you show the full error? And is your database filled with data? Is it trying to access data right away? if so, try to empty your database or disable the application connecting to the database for a minute to see if it is database related.

Comment: @killstreet It's full error
[01-Aug-2018 10:22:07 UTC] [2018-08-01 10:22:07] local.ERROR: The MAC is invalid. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Encryption\\DecryptException(code: 0): The MAC is invalid. at C:\\wamp64\\www\\newDS\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\Encrypter.php:195)"} []
I try this, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

if you copy/past the project to another computer you should clear all cache :

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: I did it, but it didn't help. And when i use php artisan route:cache i have error Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.

Comment: if you have something like 
 Route::get('/some/route', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
route:cache not working

Comment: are you have redis server on project ??

Comment: No, I haven't  redis server

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a new `APP_KEY`, which is needed to encrypt and decrypt data. When you create a new key, the data could not be decrypted anymore. You should recover your old `APP_KEY` to let the application decrypt the data to remove the error.

Comment: I use only one APP_KEY

Comment: OK so you just have copied the APP_KEY from the old location to the new location?

Comment: Yes, I use key from old project